# Reading Route Parameters Not Executing ForkJoin Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got the following routing defined for my page:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blog-posts/:postId', component: BlogPostComponent }, //this one
  { path: 'blog-posts', component: BlogComponent },
  { path: 'board-games', component: BoardGamesComponent },
  { path: 'lego', component: LegoSetsComponent },
  { path: 'now', component: NowComponent },
  { path: 'collections', component: CollectionsComponent },
  { path: 'socials', component: SocialLinksComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

The `ngOnInit` in the typescript is as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let routeParams$ = this.route.paramMap;
    routeParams$.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('params?', result);
    });
    console.log('initializing');
    forkJoin([this.blogService.getBlogPosts(), routeParams$])
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map(([blogPosts, routeParams]) => {
          {
            return {
              blogPosts,
              routeParams: routeParams,
            };
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (result: { blogPosts: BlogPost[]; routeParams: ParamMap }) => {
          console.log('doing something at all');
          const blogPost = result.blogPosts.find(
            (p) => p.postId === result.routeParams.get('postId')
          );
          console.log('blog post found', blogPost);
          this.blogPost = blogPost!;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      });
  }
```

When I visit `/blog-posts/4`, the `console.log('initializing');` logs no problem, which suggests that my routing is correct, but the `forkJoin` `subscribe` never runs, so I never see the `console.log('doing something');` log. What do I have wrong?

Comment: When all observables complete, forkJoin emit the last emitted value from each. The routeParams$ doesn't complete. So your subscribe function never run. In this case you can use combineLatest operator

Answer (score 0):

truonghungit answered it in the comments above, but the fix here was to use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`.